# Is there a way to sort digits within one cell for an alpha-numberic number in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of Alpha-numeric values in an Excel Spreadsheet. I would like to sort only a portion of the value, rather than the whole value itself.

For example:

```
0032A04550
```

I would like to subtract `0032A` from `0032A04550` to get a value of `04550` to populate new data field.

Have a list of `0032A` numbers that vary by the last 5 digits and would like to populate a column with only the last 5 digits.

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

**=MID(A1, 6, 9999)**

Comment: @Todd  If you have a related question, update your post.  If it is a new question, create a new post.